# Could we use the exotic isotope Helium-8 to synthesize super heavy atoms?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Helium-8, with 2 protons 6 neutrons, has a surprisingly long half-life of [119ms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_helium), Helium-6 is similar but all other unstable isotopes last *a few zeptoseconds* at most.

Super-heavy elements are difficulty to synthesize due to the starting materials being too neutron-poor/proton-rich. Calcium-48 alleviates the problem somewhat since it is unusually neutron rich. Could Helium-8 be an even better choice in some circumstances?

Comment: Two issues to consider- making He-8 is a whole process unto itself, and it will be hard to get much relative to a standard Ca ion beam (yes, Ca-48 is a small part of it, but it is there all the time and also doesn’t decay in flight). Then, any He-8 reaction only bumps the number of protons by two, so you will need multiple independently improbable reactions to yield the increase in protons from just one Ca reaction.